# Should we challenge the powers at be on Typography

Tags: discussion

I say this because I do believe there is a justified difference in typography and design.  I feel that many on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40151/typography) and others do not understand the differences and still feel that it is design related when it actually is different.  Should we challenge this on Meta?  I ask this because I see true value if we had our own typography area.  I personally think it can be its own entity just like GD here.  A typography section could help in others to identify fonts, font relation and suggestion, creation of fonts and  differences within serif and sans.  Focus on quality leading, kerning, tracking when developing a font.  The best reason I can say to justify this is saying that we should have only one CMS board when we clearly have a [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) board.

Comment: You should read [Robert Cartaino's post](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/8552/1589) about closing the proposal. It says what the reasoning behind the closing was and that it would be okay to start a new proposal (assuming it ends up with different scope than the original one).

Comment: awesome.  looks like I will have a lot of work on my hands to prepare for.